# How to configure AutoMapper in .Net core 2.2 for custom properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I'm setting up AutoMapper for my Asp.Net core 2.2 application. How to configure this for custom properties?

-> Added "AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection (6.0.0)" NuGet package to the solution.

-> Added "services.AddAutoMapper();" to "ConfigureServices" method in my startup.cs file.

Mapping profile file:

```
    using AutoMapper;

    namespace Api.AutoMapperProfiles
    {
        public class MappingProfile : Profile
        {
            public MappingProfile()
            {
                var map = CreateMap<System.Data.DataRow, OneViewModel>();
                map.ForAllOtherMembers(opt => opt.Ignore());
                map.ForMember(d => d.one, o => o.MapFrom(s => s["one"]));
                map.ForMember(d => d.two, o => o.MapFrom(s => s["two"]));
            }
        }
    }
```

---

Controller file:

```
  List<OneViewModel> pr = _mapper.Map<IDataReader, List<OneViewModel>>(ds.Tables[0].CreateDataReader());
```

I expect a list of "OneViewModel" from the datatable. But I get an error that "Capacity" property is not mapped. And there is not capacity property in my datatable or model.

Answer (score 0):

In your MappingProfile, you are configuring the mapping for `System.Data.DataRow` to `OneViewModel`. What you should be configuring is, `IDataReader` to `OneViewModel`.

```
// configure mapping, hope you get the idea
var map = Mapper.CreateMap<IDataReader, CustomerModel>()
  .ForMember(dest => dest.one,
      opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.GetValue(src.GetOrdinal("one")).ToString())))

// use
using (DataTableReader dr = ds.Tables[0].CreateDataReader())
{
    if (dr.HasRows)
    {
       var pr = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<IDataReader, IList<OneViewModel>>(dr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jaliya. I'm getting 2 errors with above code -----
1. (dr.HasRows) => 'IDataReader' does not contain a definition for 'HasRows' and no accessible extension method 'HasRows' accepting a first argument of type 'IDataReader' could be found. ------ 2. AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<IDataReader, IList<OneViewModel>>(dr) => Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<OneViewModel>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<OneViewModel>'

Comment: First error (dr.HasRows) is fixed. But I still see the second error. Thank you!

Comment: That resolved compile time errors. Now I get this run time error: 
Method 'get_Item' in type 'Proxy_System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[[OneViewModel, ViewModels, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]_13326799_' from assembly 'AutoMapper.Proxies, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=be96cd2c38ef1005' does not have an implementation.